# prevent line break after jeditable trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that the edit field provided by jeditable stays in the same line as the text which triggered it. I created a jsfiddle to show what I mean

https://jsfiddle.net/xu1ree7v/8/

As you can see, the edit fields are always on the next line... I tried "white-space: nowrap;" and "display: inline;" but all of that seems to be ignored by jeditable.
my javascript looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".display-date").editable('www.example.com', {
        type: 'select',
        data: "{'Belgrade':'Belgrade','Paris':'Paris','London':'London', 'selected':'Belgrade'}",
        cancel: 'cancel',
        submit: 'ok',
    });
});


$(".edit-trigger").click(function () {
    $(this).prev().trigger(".display-date");
});
```

and the html is

```
<p style="font-size:10pt; white-space: nowrap;display: inline;">Next meeting:
    <div class="display-date select_next_jc" style="font-size:10pt; white-space: nowrap;display: inline;">test-time <a class="edit-trigger">Edit</a>

    </div>
</p>
```

thanks
carl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `style: 'inherit'` in your Jeditable options:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".display-date").editable('www.example.com', {
        type: 'select',
        data: "{'Belgrade':'Belgrade','Paris':'Paris','London':'London', 'selected':'Belgrade'}",
        cancel: 'cancel',
        submit: 'ok',
        style: 'inherit'
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/06g8q2g8/

This will cause the newly created form to inherit the same style as you've set on the editable element (including `display: inline`).

Source: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable